# use python recursive function to parse a json with some regulation

Tags: python, json, validation, parsing, recursion

## Use Python to parse a json by according to his operation

### this is my intput json

```
injson = {
    "$op": "gte",
    "$params": [
        {
            "$op": "startswith",
            "$params": ["yang", "y"]
        },
        {
            "$op": "type",
            "$params": ["yang", "string"]
        }
    ]
}
```

### out is I want to get, but I want to implement with a function

```
out = "yang".startswith("y") >= isinstance("yang", str)
print(out)
```

"startswith" , "type", "gte" return Boolean

$op is what opereate need to do, $params is parameters with a list, may be many layers, I want to write a recursive function to implement it use python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting this question as "my `injson` data structure contains a series of objects that represent the components of an expression. How can I evaluate this expression and return the final result?"

The grammar of your expression language looks pretty simple: each component is either a simple value, such as "yang", or a dictionary that represents a function call. So your recursive evaluator only needs to handle those two cases. Most of the real work will be in translating your custom operators into something that Python understands.

Example implementation:

```
import operator

def check_type(obj, type_name):
    #we can't just directly use `isinstance` for type checks, because `isinstance("foo", "string")` doesn't understand what the second argument is supposed to represent.
    #so we need an extra layer here to convert type-looking strings into actual types.
    types_by_name = {"string": str, "int": int, "bool": bool} #add more types as desired
    return isinstance(obj, types_by_name[type_name])

operators_by_name = {
    "gte": operator.ge,
    "startswith": str.startswith,
    "type": check_type,
    #add more named functions as desired
}

def eval_json(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict) and "$op" in obj:
        op = operators_by_name[obj["$op"]]
        args = [eval_json(arg) for arg in obj["$params"]]
        return op(*args)
    else:
        return obj

injson = {
    "$op": "gte",
    "$params": [
        {
            "$op": "startswith",
            "$params": ["yang", "y"]
        },
        {
            "$op": "type",
            "$params": ["yang", "string"]
        }
    ]
}
print(eval_json(injson))
```

Result:

```
True
```

This is the desired result, since `"yang".startswith("y") >= isinstance("yang", str)` also evaluates to True.